# How I can change payment method order after placing order in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

how do I let customers change their payment method after placing order? Magento 2.3.3

Comment: what is your actual plan?

Comment: I need to let customers have the option to change their payment method after they placed their order but before they pay it

Comment: But after changing, how customer able to pay?

Comment: lets say customer chose to pay with bank transfer but after they create order they wish to change their payment method to cash on delivery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425066/how-to-change-payment-method-from-one-to-another-of-the-existing-order-in-magent may help